# Run automated test cases on local machine's web browser - HUDSON

Tags: testing, hudson, automated-tests

I use remote hudson server for test automation of webapplication. When I run the automated test cases they ran on the browser of that remote machine. I rather want them to run on my machine.

Is there a way I can achieve this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can run [Jenkins slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) on your machine and tie the job to it (there is such an option on the job definition page). Moreover, you can use [NodeLabel Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) and use a parameter to specify to which node you want to tie your job. For example: by default it will run on Master, but you also can specify your slave when running it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what tool you're using to drive the browser. If you're using selenium, you can set up a selenium server on your machine, then direct your tests to use your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are talking about a test browser , I assume you use the selenium plugin for hudson/jenkins. you can change the location/capabilities of the node where the test are run against in your testcode.

```
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
capabilities.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
```

also it's possible to exclude the master from the node list by editing the config file in the jenkins plugin folder

If you are refering to just restricting where the project can be run, this can be found

https://[jenkins name]/job/[jobname]/configure

under Restrict where this project can be run